# Showing a new UIView when rotates

Tags: iphone

I was following an example in the Beginning iPhone 4 book for creating a new view when the view rotates.  I have two views for this ViewController.  In

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

I add the PortraitView (typically our app starts in Landscape) as a subview

```
[self.view addSubview:PortraitView];
```

and basically hide all elements that are for landscape, and unhide all elements for Portrait.  (It seems like I need to do this since my background is clearColor and the elements from the Landscape view show through.

So now, I want to select an item in Portrait view (it's a UITableView), and go to another detailView in Portrait mode.  If the user rotates back to Landscape, then I'd like to go back to where they were in the original Landscape position.  When I show this new view when an item is selected from the UITableView, should I push a new ViewController and show its view, or should I do another show/hide addSubview?  It seems like I should push a new ViewController, but then when this ViewController rotates back to Landscape, how does it know to back to the original Landscape view since it's a different ViewController.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to design it now, for the least amount of decoupling later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider presentModalViewController:animated: for the portrait mode.

Look at the sample code for AlternateViews at

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AlternateViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008755

It presents a modal view controller for landscape mode.

Comment: This is perfect... the tutorial does exactly what I want to do... thank you... now I just need to integrate my app's functionality like this one :)